# objects in posix thread-functions

Tags: c++, class, object, pthreads, posix

I have got a main function like this:

```
    int main(){
    ....
    Protocol SPI_conn;

    SPI_conn.omap_SPI_init();
    ....
    pthread_create(&rt_OneStep0_thread, NULL, rt_OneStep0, NULL);
    ....
    }
```

where SPI_conn is an object of the class Protocol and omap_SPI_init() is a method of the same class. My thread-function looks like this:

```
extern "C" void * rt_OneStep0(void *)
{   
while (1) {
  sem_wait(&step0_semaphore);
  SPI_do();
  sem_wait(&step0_semaphore);
  }
}
```

SPI_do() is also a function of the class Protocol. My question is, how can I use the object SPI_conn with the method SPI_do. Normally you can do it by reference, but here rt_OneStep0(void*) has to be defined like this, right?

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Pass the object you create in main to the thread function via the void* arg to the thread function. Google for a pthreads tutorial - there are lots out there with examples of how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely, your prototypes are correct.
It all lies in how you can use the last parameter of `pthread_create`. It's actually a pointer to anything you want, that will be passed as the parameter to your thread's entry point (so, here, `rt_OneStep0`).

Hence, if you create your thread like this :

`pthread_create(&rt_OneStep0_thread, NULL, rt_OneStep0, &SPI_conn);`

You will receive the address of your `SPI_conn` object as the `void*` argument of your `rt_OneStep0` function. You'll just have to cast it back to the proper type and you can then use it normally.

```
extern "C" void * rt_OneStep0(void *arg)
{
      Protocol *my_object = static_cast<Protocol*>(arg);   
      //... 
}
```

However, since you're dealing with threads and you'll be sharing an object created on your main thread, be careful about concurrency and race conditions.

Comment: and then i can go with that?
       `my_object->SPI_do();`

Comment: Absolutely. Once you have casted your argument back to the proper type you can use it normally.